# Master/Detail navigation with a "toolbar" on Detail views

Tags: android, ios, xaml, layout, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin Forms, I would like to make a layout like this. Basically it's a `MasterDetailPage`. But I want a "toolbar" that is kept and shared along all the Detail pages.

[image: My layout]

As usual, the Master acts as a sidebar on the left side, and the Detail is shown on the right side. The Master has buttons to switch the Detail page.

**Now, the difficult part:** I also want to have another bar that should appear at the top (or bottom) of the Detail view in order to navigate from it, since it will have the most common sections the user will want to navigate to (without having to use the side bar).

How can I get this layout?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done (by the way, avoid Yes/No kind of questions):

What you want to do is to have **two Fragments** (side-bar and the bottom-bar) and **one fragment place-holder** as `FrameLayout` (to load details content). You will then use `FragmentTransactions` to "`replace`" the placeholder-fragment based on what has been selected on the side-bar just as you would in a normal mater/list-details use case.

So supposing I clicked on "Contacts" side-bar, I could have code like this:

```
      ...
      case CONTACT_SELECT : 
       ContactsFragment contactFragment = new ContactFragment(<some-params-if-needed>);
       FragmentTransaction ft = get<Support>FragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       ft.replace(R.id.id_of_your_placeholder_framelayout, contactFragment);
       ft.commit();
    break;

    case SOMETHING_ELSE : ...
```

Unless I missed something special about your use case, I think the above proposal should server you well.

I hope this helps.

The official guide might also help: [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Comment: Nice! But I don't think that will work for Xamarin Forms. The Fragments feature seems to be Android only. I would like to avoid making different layouts for each OS.